# Combining cells in table?

Tags: css, video

How do I embed a `youtube` video to a `table`?

I want the left and right columns to be 2 `rows` high and the middle column to have 2 cells, I want the video in the bottom cell and the text in the top but I can't figure out how to move it there

```
<div class="cbody">
        <table class="ctable">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" style="width:105px"><img class="cimg1" src="meh.png" alt=" " width="100px" height="500px"></td>
                <td><p class="ctxt">
                my text here
                </p></td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="width:105px"><img class="cimg2" src="meh.png" alt=" " width="100px" height="500px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xI_6oLPC-S0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and CSS...

```
.cbody {
width:800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-style:solid;
border-width:3px;
}

.cimg1 {
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
float:left;
}

.cimg2 {
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
float:right;
}

.ctxt {
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
text-align:center;

}

.ctable {
width:800px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `<td>` tags around the `<iframe>`, i.e.:

```
<td>
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xI_6oLPC-S0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</td>
```

You should also think about using `<th>` instead of `<td>` where you want to put your text in.